# Restrict super user write access to some files

Tags: filesystem, root, sip

Is there a way to add folders to the SIP ([System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)) configurations in order to prevent them to be modified by the root user?
Or any other way not involving [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)? 
I want to protect the host file so I can block distracting websites and not being able to modify it as a root user. As a developer, I still need to be a root user so deleting `sudo` is not an option.

I'm looking for a solution which is independent from my internet connection.

Comment: The `root` user has **by design** access to all files on the system. I don''t think you can extend SIP to protect user-defined folders or files. You could however, as explained here: https://support.apple.com/HT204012, disable the `root` user. The other option would be to place those files on a read-only partition (but then they wouldn't be writeable for anyone...). I'd be helpful if you explained why you think that `root` access to some files (which files?) is a problem.

Comment: I want to be unable to modify the host file. I use this file to block distracting websites but it's too easy comment some lines: `sudo vim /etc/hosts`.
If I'd need  to reboot and disable SIP it would make things harder and thus make me avoid to modify the host file

Comment: Why don't you delete the `sudo` command? If you need to modify `/etc/hosts`, you will need to boot in single user mode (https://support.apple.com/HT201573), remount the root file system in read/write mode and only then will you be able to make changes to `/etc/hosts`. The downside is that you won't be able to execute commands as root with Terminal.

Comment: As a developper, deleting the sudo command is unfortunately not a solution. That's why I was thinking about something involving SIP, since it seems to be the only thing that restricts root access to files.

Comment: Disabling the `root` user won't accomplish anything, `sudo` will still work.

Comment: If you want to temporarily block certain sites https://freedom.to/ might help, or a set of rules in Little Snitch

Answer (score 2):

## SelfControl

[SelfControl](https://selfcontrolapp.com) is an open source project aimed at restricting distractions:

> SelfControl is a free and open-source application for macOS that lets you block your own access to distracting websites, your mail servers, or anything else on the Internet. Just set a period of time to block for, add sites to your blacklist, and click "Start." Until that timer expires, you will be unable to access those sites—even if you restart your computer or delete the application.

## Pi-Hole

To block distracting websites and services on all your devices, consider blocking them on your network using [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net).

With this approach you avoid needing to modify your macOS configuration.

Comment: As I don't have a fixed place where I live and I'm often using tethering, this won't work for me.

Comment: I have added a local option, SelfControl.